# React js routing not working when html template script is present

Tags: reactjs, react-router

**Problem**

Asp.net core 2.0 and react js app is live at [here](http://www.lekkibet.com/). I have done everything i could do to make (navigation) routing work but unfortunately it is still not working. Website is hosted on iis.

**Index.js**

```
    import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {
    Route,
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch
} from "react-router-dom";

import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import Footer from './components/layout/footer';
import Header from './components/layout/header';

import Home from './Components/home'
import Contact from './Components/contact';
import Results from './Components/results';
import Promotions from './Components/promotions';
import InPlay from './Components/in_play';
import Stats from './Components/statistics';

import Notfound from './notfound';

const routing = (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
                <Route path="/results" component={Results} />
                <Route path="/promotions" component={Promotions} />
                <Route path="/inplay" component={InPlay} />
                <Route path="/stats" component={Stats} />

                <Route component={Notfound} />
            </Switch>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById("root"));

registerServiceWorker();

module.hot.accept();
```

**And Header.js**

```
<li className="rd-nav-item">
<Link to="/" className="rd-nav-link" href="/">Home</Link>
</li>
<li className="rd-nav-item">
<Link to="/inplay" className="rd-nav-link">In-Play</Link>
</li>
<li className="rd-nav-item">
<Link to="/promotions" className="rd-nav-link">Promotions</Link>
</li>
<li className="rd-nav-item">
<Link to="/stats" className="rd-nav-link">Statistics</Link>
</li>

other list elements
```

**---------Update---------**

I have found that if i comment out "script.js" which is a file of html template then despite design issue, routing work. Its certainly an issue with js script [here](https://gist.github.com/suhail339/e0a8037c11e52942c91a218a21cd0c99).

Routing is not working as full app loads on navigation. No related console error.

Now i have narrowed down the problem, its actually "pageTransition" plugin. May be i need to work this page transition with react js.

```
Further improvements are made by changing the order of script loading in index.html, problematic script.js by loading it after bundle.js.
```

**-------update end-------**

If someone have idea or information, please let me know. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please share you controller code

Comment: Can you manually navigate to page routes point to? For example to `http://your-site/inplay`?

Comment: No, routing i not working either way http://www.lekkibet.com/promotions

Comment: app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });

Comment: add these lines in configure method is startup class and see if this will work. I hope this will work

Comment: @UxmaanAli thanks for reply, these settings won't work since i am using aspnet core version 1.0.0 in project.

Comment: @UxmaanAli please see updated question.

Comment: I tried your website with and without the code and the page did not full reload on navigation.

Comment: @i have updated the site with routing is enabled now, changed the order of scripts loading.